# Unable to use pip after installation / upgrading pip on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip

After I install `pip` on windows10 ; it says `Successfully Installed`

But when I try to use it says `pip is not recognized as an internal or external command`

[image: Image to explain]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 1):

You have to preface it with

```
py -m pip
```

in order to have the cmd line interpret it as a python command, like you did when you installed it

Answer (score 0):

the install script says

```
    WARNING: The script pip.exe, pip3.10.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 
'C:\Users\Mo3az\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python310\Scripts' 
which is not on PATH 

Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this 
warning use --no-warn-script-location
```

(I typed it myself this might contain some typo)

add `C:\Users\Mo3az\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python310\Scripts`

to PATH then you will be able to run pip3
[how to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)